# Find the indexes of the elements of a List presentin another List

Tags: c#, linq, list, ienumerable

I have two Lists: ListA and ListB. Some of the elements in ListB are contained in ListA, which contains also elements from other lists. My question is:

How can I find the indexes of the elements of ListA contained in ListB?

Lets say

```
ListA = [A B D E J]
ListB = [A B C H J K L M N O P R Q Z]
```

I want this result:

```
ListC = [0 1 -1 -1 4]
```

or just

```
ListC = [0 1 4]
```

Thank you!

Comment: What are the exact element type of the list, is it `char`, `string` or some other custom class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ListA.Select(x => ListB.IndexOf(x))
```

To understand this code you need to be able to understand both `Select` and `IndexOf`. Both are simple, common and important, so make sure you find out how to use them.